# How to tell whether a source code is written in Visual Basic or VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net

I have never used Visual Basic before.

I have some source code for a project to look at. How can I tell whether the code has been written in VB or VB.Net?

Thanks.

---

I had a second look, it does not have any VB6 or VB.Net extension, but it has some ASP files, 1 CSS file and some .XLST extension files with HTML and what seems to be either VB or maybe VBScript inside.. I am not entirely sure whether it is VB or VBScript inside.

Comment: +1, this used to be a huge problem when Googling for code examples online.  Nobody ever specified VB 5/6, or .NET, so it took some time to find the right stuff.

Comment: I have some code which looks like below  in a .aspx page within <% %> block, it is VB script or VB.NET code                                                                                                              Dim myConnection As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        Dim myCommand As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
        Dim myParameter As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter
        Dim myDataReader As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the project file has the extension .VBP then it is VB6. If you have a .VBPROJ file then it is VB.NET

If you don't have a project file, then the best indicators are `Import` directives or object oriented programming keywords like `Inherits` or `Implements`

Comment: Thanks. I just had a second look. It seems like it might actually be some ASP file with VBScripting inside. Although i am not certain... since I have used neither before.

Comment: @Rosie Classic Asp (.asp extension, not .aspx) used VBScript.

Answer (score 4):

Files created from Visual Basic 6.0 will have a .bas extension.  Files created from Visual Studio .NET and up will have a .vb extention.  This isn't a perfect test, but it might get you close.

Comment: Only modules had the .bas extension.

Comment: VB.Net supports all vb6 file extensions. Definitely a strong indicator though

Comment: Thanks, it seems like it has neither. it has some ASP files, one CSS file, and some XSLT files with HTML and what seems to be some Visual Basic or VBScripting code inside?

Comment: I would think that is VBScript then

Answer (score 3):

There's no definitive answer here because there is a large margin of compatibility between the languages.  For example the following is legal in both VB.Net and VB6

```
Function Add(ByVal x, ByVal y)
  Add = x + y
End Function
```

That being said, any of the following wound be a strong indicator of VB.Net code

- `Import` directives
- `SyncLock`, `Using` statements
- `Friend`, `Protected` access modifier
- `ByRef` parameter modifier

And the following would be a strong indicator of VB6

- `Global` access modfifier

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed explanation. I just had a second look. It seems like it might actually be some ASP file with VBScripting inside. Although i am not certain... since I have used neither before.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can look for is a `<filename>.vbproj` file. If you see that then you've got a  Visual Studio VB.Net project. If the file is missing that doesn't necessarily mean its VB6 though.

If you see `<filename>.frm` files then you've got VB6 code.

Comment: thanks, it has neither. It seems like it has some ASP one CSS file, and some .XSLT extension files. I am guessing this maybe a .Net project containing VB scripting code? Im a little confused.